# entity framework 4.1 on web server

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting an error when I delpoy my solution to the web server saying that it cannot load the assembly Entity Framework 4.1.  I have recently installed .NET framework 4 on the web server in order to make use of the new entity framework.  Do I need to install EF 4.1 on the web server or is there any way to get around that?

I have tried to copy local the Entity Framework reference in my project.

Comment: Is your application pool running .NET 4? You must copy EntityFramework.dll as part of your application (to its `bin` directory).

Comment: yes my app pool is running .net 4.  I thought that copying the reference local would do this?

Comment: What does local mean? Web application has strict rules where you have to place dlls. You can also install EntityFramework.dll to GAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.

When I did a publish to the file system it did not copy over the Entity Framework dll even though I set Copy local to true.  Maybe this is an error in the publishing feature.  I found the dll in the bin / debug folder of my project and copied them over the web server.

Works great!

Thanks to everyone that helped!

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework 4.1 isn't part of .net 4. You should go ahead and install it on the server if you can. If not, make sure you set CopyLocal=True on the relevant references and see if that's enough to let it work (not sure if it is for EF 4.1 or not).